# Change Key's Function If Held (Tab>Super;Apostrophe>CTRL)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap, xmonad

I'd really love tab and apostrophe to work as they are supposed to, but then change to Super and Ctrl respectively when held. If I can figure out how to do this, I'm gonna be doing it all over my keyboard. Is this something I can do with Xkb?

I was doing this with QMK on my homemade keyboards and it was a gamechanger.

Please tell me that Linux can do this!

Edit: Well alright. I've found a tool, [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape), whose purpose is exactly this. I haven't yet implemented it on my system, though. If anybody has gotten setups like this working, then feel free to post your dot files/instructions/hangups below! In the meanwhile I'll plug away at it in my scarce free-time.

I fear that it may be defunct, as it doesn't seem to have been maintained in two years, but it does operate on some more fundamental parts of the operating system, so maybe it has needed no maintenence?

Comment: How would it work?  Wouldn't you type <tab><tab><tab><tab><tab><tab> every time you held it because you wanted <super>?

Comment: xcape do what you mean and is still functionnal,